# IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type to required type

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Here's the error I'm receiving.

```
       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [code.ProductFieldSetMapper] to required type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper] for property 'FieldSetMapper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:450)
... 23 more
```

Here's my context file (FileReaderConfig.xml)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file:./output.txt" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="PRODUCT_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="code.ProductFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<job id="importProducts" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="readWriteProducts">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

Here's the interface (FieldSetMapper.java)
           package code;

```
 import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

 public interface FieldSetMapper<T> {
T mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException;
 }
```

Here's ProductFieldSetMapper.java

```
 package code;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class ProductFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Product> {

public Product mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setId(fieldSet.readString("PRODUCT_ID"));
    product.setName(fieldSet.readString("NAME"));
    product.setDescription(fieldSet.readString("DESCRIPTION"));
    product.setPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal("PRICE"));
    return product;
}

}
```

And here's the class that I'm running (Runner.java)
    package code;

```
import org.omg.PortableInterceptor.SYSTEM_EXCEPTION;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException, BindException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Product product;
     ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("FileReaderConfig.xml");

    ProductFieldSetMapper obj = (ProductFieldSetMapper) context.getBean("FieldSetMapper");

     product = (Product) obj.mapFieldSet((FieldSet)context.getBean("lineTokenizer"));

System.out.println(product.getDescription() + ""+product.getId()+""+product.getName());


}
}
```

I don't see where (or why for that matter)my code is attempting to convert a ProductFieldSetMapper into a FieldSetMapper (which is just an interface, I understand that won't work).

BTW, Product.java is a POJO with  variables and their respective setters and getters.

Answer (score 2):

The error was the result of me using my own interface rather than the one provided by Spring. I deleted my interface class and had ProductFieldSetMapper implement org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper after importing it. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductFieldSetMapper obj = 
(ProductFieldSetMapper) context.getBean("FieldSetMapper");
```

Should be

```
ProductFieldSetMapper obj = 
(ProductFieldSetMapper) context.getBean("fieldSetMapper");
```

See your bean declaration.

```
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="code.ProductFieldSetMapper" />
        </property>
```

Comment: Good catch, however it doesn't solve the problem, still same error.

Comment: I think my ProductFieldSetMapper needs to extend the spring version of FieldSetMapper rather than the interface I wrote. Any idea on how to do that? Would I just delete my own interface and import the one provided by spring before calling 'implements'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code with some correction:

**Runner.java** (use `DelimitedLineTokenizer` class to tokenize a comma separated string into `FieldSet` that is further used to map it with an object (Product) via `ProductFieldSetMapper` class)

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "FileReaderConfig.xml");

ProductFieldSetMapper obj = (ProductFieldSetMapper) context.getBean("fieldSetMapper");

DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = (DelimitedLineTokenizer) context
        .getBean("lineTokenizer");

FieldSet fieldSet = tokenizer.tokenize("1,Pepsi,Cold drinks,30");

Product product = (Product) obj.mapFieldSet(fieldSet);

System.out.println(product.getDescription() + "-" + product.getId() + "-"
        + product.getName());
```

**Config xml file:** (No need to declare any beans or jobs other than two defined below because you are not using it anywhere in you `Main` class)

```
<bean id="lineTokenizer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="PRODUCT_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE" />
</bean>

<bean id="fieldSetMapper" class="com.spring.batch.domain.ProductFieldSetMapper" />
```

**ProductFieldSetMapper.java:** (There is no need to define your custom `FieldSetMapper`)

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class ProductFieldSetMapper implements org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper<Product> {

    public Product mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(fieldSet.readString("PRODUCT_ID"));
        product.setName(fieldSet.readString("NAME"));
        product.setDescription(fieldSet.readString("DESCRIPTION"));
        product.setPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal("PRICE"));
        return product;
    }
}
```

---

**For a detailed sample please read it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360709/how-to-process-multiple-lines-with-the-spring-batch?answertab=votes#tab-top) with extra functionality using spring batch jobs.**

Comment: Please let me if there is any confusion.

Comment: First, thanks for the much neater code. The purpose though is to read from a file, output.txt (that's my flat file, sry for the misleading name, should've been something else). I'm conceptually having a hard time understanding how the code reads the lines and turns them into fieldSet's, which I can then work with.

Comment: Here's what output.txt would look like. PRODUCT_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE
PR210,BlackBerry 8100 Pearl,A cell phone,124.60
PR211,Sony Ericsson W810i,Yet another cell phone!,139.45
PR212,Samsung MM-A900M Ace,A cell phone,97.80
PR213,Toshiba M285-E 14,A cell phone,166.20
PR214,Nokia 2610 Phone,A cell phone,145.50

Comment: Have you read my sample that I have shared as a link? Use `FlatFileItemReader` that reads line by line from file and assign it into `FieldSet` where you have formed a `Product` object that is used further to process. Here tokenlizer comes into picture to create a `FieldSet` object.

Comment: Didn't even notice the last sentence there, I'll give it a read over and comment if I'm still confused. Thx.

Comment: Hope, you have fixed it.

Comment: I'm using the code you supplied in that link, but I'm getting the most ridiculous error. Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'job'.           It refers to this line in the jobs.xml        <job id="job" restartable="false" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

Comment: Try to run it in an separate application. Its a working sample.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49761/discussion-between-serge-and-braj)